# The strange behavior of the `operator string()` type conversion function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a `C` class and I want to convert it to `string` by using the `operator string()` syntax, but as I wrote in the comment, something strange happens.

```cpp
class C {
public:
    operator string()
    {
        return string("anything");
    }
};
int main()
{
    C c;
    cout << string("test:").append(c) << endl; //success
    //cout << string("test:")+c<< endl;//fail
    //cout << c.append("test:") << endl;//fail
    cout << string("test:") + static_cast<string>(c) << endl;//success
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> //cout << string("test:")+c<< endl;//fail
> ```

[`std::operator+(std::basic_string)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) are templates. Implicit conversion won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which causes the deduction failing on the 2nd operand `c`.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

And

> ```
> //cout << c.append("test:") << endl;//fail
> ```

`C` doesn't have member function named `append`, then the code fails. You can convert `c` to `std::string` explicitly then call `append` on it like `static_cast<string>(c).append("test:")`.

> ```
> cout << string("test:").append(c) << endl; //success
> ```

`string("test:").append` expects an `std::string`, then `c` is converted to `std::string` implicitly and passed to `append`. (Note that `append` are non-template member functions.)

> ```
> cout << string("test:") + static_cast<string>(c) << endl;//success
> ```

`c` is converted to `std::string` explicitly, then two `std::string`s are passed to `std::operator+(std::basic_string)`.

Comment: Just in case if you want to enable implicit conversions in your own function when CTAD : [#link](https://godbolt.org/z/Ka8vvY19e). In C++20, `std::type_identity` is added.

Comment: Oops, I mean TAD not CTAD :-(